# When to build in application/classes vs modules?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm fairly new to Kohana but I like the framework. I've hit a bit of an issue where I need to build a theme system into my application. It is very much application specific and there really won't be any reason to share it down the track. Initially I built it into the modules system within Kohana but now need to expand it. I haven't seen much reference for it but is it best practice to build all support classes like this into the modules or is it best practice to keep application-specific classes etc housed within application/classes?

On a side note, are there any good theme-system examples for Kohana? I really like how Drupal manages its themes and sub-themes and was wanting to emulate a very basic version of this inside my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with that, anything specific to the application and has no real reuse should be put into the application directory. I like to use modules for fairly generic modules. Examples would be:

- *contact* - Many websites have contact forms.
- *email* - Can be used in lots of places.

etc ...

For your case, you might consider building a templating engine and putting that into a module (it's generic), then simply housing the application specific theme into the application directory where your module can load and use it.